# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater

Tags: icefaces

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater

Please suggest I am trying to configure ICEFaces on Tomcat

Comment: This doesn't belong here (it is a server configuration question, not a programming question) and it has almost no detail -- or punctuation, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the relevant classes to your server configuration xml.

See the relevant Tomcat/IceFACES examples on the ICEFaces website. Or use a good IDE with ICEFaces plugins which will do the configuration for you. Netbeans works well with ICEFaces and Tomcat.